# Write Chinese chars to a text file using vbscript

Tags: string, vbscript, text-files, cjk

I'm trying to write some Chinese characters to a text file using

```
Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set outputFile = myFSO.OpenTextFile(getOutputName(Argument, getMsiFileName(Wscript.Arguments)), forWriting, True)
outputFile.WriteLine(s)
```

The variable `s` contains a Chinese character that I read from the other file. I echo `s` value and I can see the s correctly in the screen. However, for some reason the script stops running after `outputFile.WriteLine(s)` without returning any error message.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's got something to do with character encoding. Try directly specifying the Unicode format for the file in the last parameter of the `OpenTextFile` method:

```
Const Unicode = -1
Set outputFile = myFSO.OpenTextFile(getOutputName(Argument, getMsiFileName(Wscript.Arguments)), forWriting, True, Unicode)
```

Also, you need to close the file after writing to it:

```
outputFile.Close
```

If this doesn't help, try error handling like [AnthonyWJones suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232714/write-chinese-chars-to-a-text-file-using-vbscript/2232846#2232846).

Comment: +1, Nice catch, I missed that last parameter and was distracted by what still is in-explicable behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
MsgBox "Writing Line"
On Error Resume Next
outputFile.WriteLine s '' # Removed ( ) that shouldn't be there.
MsgBox "Err " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0
```

What do you get?

Comment: The script doesn't prompt anything, and the text file that the script is supposed to write to gets created but it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

Things had changed along win versions. This works on Win10:

```
Set outputfile = myFSO.CreateTextFile(filename,True,True)
```

The 3rd arg is bool true/false for unicode/ascii [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx). Surprisingly, when using myFSO.OpenTextFile the arg is int with 1 (not -1) for unicode [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018(v=vs.60).aspx).

Documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018(v=vs.60).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx