# How can I save non-Latin characters in a text file via VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, non-latin

Chinese characters cannot be saved in a text file via VBScript.

The VBScript is in a folder whose name is in Chinese: 视窗. The script will create a text file, in which the current working directory will be shown. The Chinese characters cannot be saved in the file. Windows Script Host says "Error: Invalid procedure call or argument". The error will not arise if the folder name is in English.

```
Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
Set objFSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Path & "\Testing.txt", 8, True)    
objFile.WriteLine Path
objFile.close
```

Is it possible for VBScript to save a file path that contains Chinese characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `openTextFile` has another optional parameter - `format`. Its value is 0 by default which opens the file in ASCII format. To save the chinese characters in the file, you can open the file in UNICODE format by specifying the value of the parameter `format = -1`. Here is the **[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method)**.

```
objFso.openTextFile(path,8, true, -1)             '-1 = TriStateTrue = Opens the file as Unicode
```

```
path = split(wscript.scriptFullName, wscript.scriptname)(0) & "Testing.txt"
set objFso = createObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set objFile = objFso.openTextFile(path,8, true, -1)
objFile.write path
objFile.Close
set objFile = Nothing
set objFso = Nothing
```

Comment: [Already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2232984/692942) over 8 years ago.